# Is there an ActionScript library to create Illustrator files?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-illustrator, alivepdf

Is there an AS3 library to create Illustrator files? OR do you have an example creating an AI file with AS3?

An alternative and very very last resort is to create a PDF with AlivePDF and see if Illustrator can import that but that seems like a hack and I'm concerned it will lose fidelity. I'm working on very hifi subpixel positioning here of text data. No offense to Alive PDF it may work fine.

Comment: Legacy formats like .ai and .psd are really complicated. You'll be hard pressed to find a library that lets you generate these files. Try PDF or SVG instead. Both formats are public standards and are well supported by the community at large.

Comment: I've heard that before. Thanks for the advice

Comment: I ended up exporting to both SVG and FXG. FXG was much easier and had higher fidelity. With SVG I had to manually set the first text line position to around 75% of the font size so it wasn't off screen and position each additional text line after that so they didn't all overlap. Illustrator kept the single text field from FXG but it created multiple lines with SVG. History lesson: Both formats were made by Adobe with FXG being made about 10 years later.

Answer (score 1):

There is an old trick you could try... if your output is on the stage at runtime you could use the print command and in the print menu print it to PDF.

It's good enough for quick prototyping and getting random generated patterns into Illustrator.